# If - Else on Pirates Un-resolved

Tags: android, if-statement, sharedpreferences, live-wallpaper

Could you someone show me how to create an if - else statements with two sets of R.drawable.images pirates?

I've tried, but I got an error code saying ***pirates*** is un-resolved.

Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),**pirates**[i]);

This is what I have in the preferences:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:key="wallpaper_settings"
android:title="@string/wallpaper_settings" >  <!--must be the same callout from 
values->strings-->

<ListPreference               
    android:key="speed"
    android:title="@string/speed_title"
    android:entries="@array/timelist"
    android:entryValues="@array/actualtime"
    android:summary="@string/speed_summary" >              
</ListPreference>

  <CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="checkbox"
    android:title="Nature Pictures"
    android:summary="For Nature Pictures Option"
    android:defaultValue="false" />
```

Main Activity:

```
     public class main_activity extends WallpaperService {

     public static final String SHARED_PREFS_NAME="settings_menu";


   @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

   @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

   @Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    return new wallpaperEngine();   
}

class wallpaperEngine extends Engine implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{


    private final Handler mhandler = new Handler();


    //defines variables


    private final Runnable drawrunnable = new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() {
            drawFrame();
        }
    };
    private int i = 0;
    private boolean mVisible;
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private boolean mcheckbox = false;
    public int mSpeed = 10;

         int[] pirates = {
            R.drawable.image_1,
            R.drawable.image_2,
            R.drawable.image_3,
            R.drawable.image_4

    };

       //For Nature Pictures
         int[] pirates = {
            R.drawable.image_a1,
            R.drawable.image_a2,
            R.drawable.image_a3,
            R.drawable.image_a4

    };

  .......
  ......

   Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),pirates[i]);

        i++;

        if (i == 14) {
            i = 0;
```

Thank you very much

Comment: We need a better context of where all of this is inside of your `Activity`. It looks like a variable scope issue

Comment: Thank you for a comment CodeMagic.  What's variable scope issue?  I just added more codes to the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to create two arrays of int, holding different set of images. But you are using the same variable name `pirates`. I would suggest you define two different variables `int[] pirates` and `int[] piratesNatural` and then switch between those two arrays when you need one and the other.

```
Bitmap icon; 
if(natural)  
  icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),piratesNatural[i]);   
else
  icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),pirates[i]);
```

Comment: Ahh you guys are genius.  I spent alot of time trying to make it work.  But it only took you a few mins to figure it out.  Great thanks.  I will try this method when I get home.  I am a beginner dev :-(  Thank you and thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark it as the correct answer if it worked for you.

Comment: I just got it to work!  Yay, Thank you very much!  One question though, how come the slideshow switches to the next picture whenever I open/close a different app?  I know it has nothing to do with the help that you provided me today.  Do you know what causes this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you doing animation?

```
int frame=0;
int frametime=24;

Bitmap icon1 BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image_1,);
Bitmap icon2 BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image_2,);
Bitmap icon3 BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image_3,);
Bitmap icon4 BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image_4,);



//in update
frametime--;
if(frametime<=0){
frame++;
frametime=24;
}
if(frame>3){
frame=0;
}



//in onDraw

switch(frame){

case 0:
canvas.drawBitmap(icon1,x,y,null);
break;
case 1:
canvas.drawBitmap(icon2,x,y,null);
break;
case 2:
canvas.drawBitmap(icon3,x,y,null);
break;
case 3:
canvas.drawBitmap(icon4,x,y,null);
break;
default:
canvas.drawBitmap(icon1,x,y,null);
break;}
```